# The IControllerFactory 'MyWebSite.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Admin'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, ninject

I am getting the above when I try and open a view in a controller in an Area. Ninject is set up as follows:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new RLSBCWebSiteServices());

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext context, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        return (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private class MyWebSiteServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IMatchesRepository>().To<SqlMatchesRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
                ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyWebSiteDb"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

If I place a breakpoint in the code, I see the RequestContext context contains the following values:

```
context.RouteData.DataTokens.Values[0] = “MyWebSite.WebUI.Areas.Visitor”  context.RouteData.DataTokens.Values[1] = “Visitor” which is the Area  
context.RouteData.Values.Values[0] = “admin” which is the Controller  
context.RouteData.Values.Values[1] = “register” which is the View
```

However controllerType == null, instead on the controller name.

This transfer to the new page is being triggered by

```
Html.ActionLink("here", "Register", "Admin", new { area = "Visitor" }, null)
```

which is on the Login page. However the same thing happens if I enter

```
http://example.com/Visitor/admin/register
```

into IE8

The area registration is as follows:

```
public class VisitorAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName { get { return "Visitor"; } }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Visitor_default",
            "Visitor/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Register", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Has anyone managed to get Areas working with NinjectControllerFactory, or is there something wrong with my set-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating your own NinjectControllerFactory use the latest version of Ninject.Web.Mvc. It supports Areas. See: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc

Comment: I did look at this when I downloaded Ninject in the first place, but I thought that the .dll I used was the compiled version of this. So, I have now downloaded this version but the docs are very sparse. If there something you could suggest that would help me to set things up?

Comment: Take a look at the sample application. That comes with the source code

Comment: I have downloaded the source, installed it and successfully displayed the Ninject website. Looking through the source, it is far more complicated than I want, what with Spark, Elmah, Newtonsoft etc. A lot of it is above me. I notice that you do not use Areas in your website. I also had a good look at JavascriptRouteGenerator.cs. There appears to be nothing in there that would suggest it handles Areas. I have made some changes based on the source code, which are too big to list here. I am still getting an error message saying it can't find the requested url.

Comment: Oh no. I do not mean the Website. I mean the Sample application of the MVC extension: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/tree/master/mvc2/src/SampleApplication/

Comment: I'm sorry about this but I do not understand from the web page you list what it is I am supposed to download for the sample application. There is nothing in the download button that seems to apply. I have downloaded "Ninject.Web.Mvc2-2.1.0.29-RC1-V2.2-release-net-3.5.zip — MVC2 - Release Candidate 1 for Ninject 2.2" from the downloads. This just contains .dlls basically, including System.Web.MVC. The only problem is that it is version 1.0 which doesn't support Areas. It needs to be version 2.0.

Comment: I have created a project containing the sample application. I am having problems with the IsValid routine in SampleApplication.Models.Account. The type of ValidationResult is not recognised. I am getting the message "The type or namespace name 'ValidationResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I have the same using statements so maybe I am missing a namespace. Any sugestions?

Comment: Looking through some of the other code, it seems that the demo has been written using ASP.NET 4.0. Unfortunately, being retired, I cannot afford to upgrade from .NET 3.5 SP1. Is that why ValidationResult could not be found? Your use of <%: %> rather than <%= %> is also being flagged as unresolvable.

Comment: Sry for my last comment. It takes a lot of time to maintain Ninject so please try to avoid asking questins to which the answer is found within seconds. I prefer investing this time into making Ninject a better framework.

Yes the solution is .NET 4.0 and needs to be converted in your case. You can remove lots of things form the sample application because you are only interestes in the area part. So remove all that is not compiling.

Comment: I'm sorry, also. I really do appreciate your help, and understand your priorities. Since my retirement, I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC and C# to keep my brain active. Retiring from Management, my programming days were pre ASP.NET, C# so I am finding the new concepts hard to get my head round. Everything is OK till I hit  problem. Mostly I can solve things, but when everything looks as it should be and it still doesn't work, that is when I have problems. Finding the solution on the Web is not easy because authors sometimes assume their audience know more than they do and are sparse on detail.

Comment: Thank you for your perseverence and support. I have got a version with areas working using Ninject. I created a new ASP.NET MVC2 Web App, added an Area and added Ninject to Global.asax.cs. Everything is working as I expect. I am finally happy that I know what I'm doing - until the next problem, that is.

Comment: Just to let you know, I have managed to get my original web site working with Areas using Ninject. Thanks for your patient support.

Answer (score 1):

Check your controller and action name in view. I also got same error as an action name was wrong.